# Java version not recognized when JAVA_HOME defined for a particular USERACCOUNT

Tags: java, eclipse, environment-variables, jdk, jre

I have been struck with problem on my development box.
I have JRE6 on my system and **NO ADMIN RIGHTS**.
 
Used this command to add user variables 
`rundll32 sysdm.cpl,EditEnvironmentVariables`
I have defined **JAVA_HOME** under user variables with proper path to my JRE

now when i check through by `run>cmd>java-version` It says java is not recognized.

When i check the path by command echo %JAVA_HOME% it shows the path of my JRE.And i have tried checking the environment variables using 
`set >env.txt` The defined environment variable is present.

I am not able to investigate why JAVA is not recognized when I check in command prompt through `java -version`.
**Moreover my eclipse kepler does not opens up says there is no JRE or JDK available in `C:\eclipse\jre\bin\javaw.x`**
Copied this file from JRE folder but that also did not helped in solving the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a Long Search i have found the solution for the following problem.Hope this will be quick help for others.

If **NO ADMIN ACCESS**.
Then you can create a USER Variable by hitting this in command prompt.

`rundll32 sysdm.cpl,EditEnvironmentVariables`
Here you can define your **JAVA_HOME** variable with the path to your JDK or JRE like `C:\Program Files\Java\jre7`
**But you are still not done,the above JAVA_HOME is of no use unless you define the PATH variable**
So define the `Path` variable for user variables with bin directory like `C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin`
Now this will make the System Variable and User Variable path merge.

> Check in command prompt java -version.It will show the version of your JRE/JDK